# What's security-only patch release and how to apply it?

Tags: magento2, security, patches, version

I noticed we have security-only patch releases, what's it and how to use it?

An example of these security-only patch releases, instead of having Magento 2.3.2 my client has installed **Magento 2.3.3-p1**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now you have the option to take a lighter security-only patch release when you need to, which lets you remain secure for as long as six months before picking up a full release.

Security patches use the Composer naming convention 2.3.3-px. Use Composer to specify a patch. For example, to download the Magento Commerce 2.3.2-p1 meta-package you can use:

```
composer require magento/product-community-edition=2.3.3-p1
```

The security-only patch will be based on the latest prior full patch release on our most recent release line to give you a possible upgrade path like this:

[image: Magento security-only patch release]

References:

[Introducing the New Security-only Patch Release](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-DevBlog/Introducing-the-New-Security-only-Patch-Release/ba-p/141287)

[Devdocs: Upgrade to a security-only patch release](https://devdocs-beta.magento.com/guides/v2.3/comp-mgr/cli/cli-upgrade.html#example---security-patch)

Comment: does this mean that Magento no longer will provide patches in a regular format like .patch files?

Comment: Hi @underser, they didn't stop the patches.